# Is there a standard way to swap arguments for a binary predicate?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to find last value in a container that is less-than-or equal using `std::lower_bound` (that finds greater-than-or-equal), and have a comparison predicate for my type , f.e.

`bool valComp(MyType lhs MyType rhs){ return lhs.value_ < rhs.value_; }`

Can I somehow concisely call reverse `std::lower_bound` with reversed arguments to the predicate

`std::lower_bound(myVec.rbegin(), myVec.rend(), myVal, std::i_dont_know(valComp));`

or am I better off duplicating the predicate / manually swapping them in a lambda / rolling my own template?

Comment: *"first value in a container that is less-than-or equal"*: `(!vec.empty() && *std::begin(vec) <= myVal) ? std::begin(vec) : std::end(vec)` :-) you probably want **last**

Comment: Yeah, all this reversing is a little confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda is quite short:

```cpp
// std::lower_bound(myVec.rbegin(), myVec.rend(), myVal,
    [&valComp](const auto& l, const auto& r) { return valComp(r, l); }
// );
```

The standard built-in solution would be `std::bind`

```cpp
// std::lower_bound(myVec.rbegin(), myVec.rend(), myVal,
    std::bind(valComp, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_1)
// );
```

But lambdas are universally more readable. You can make a helper function to make this simpler at the point of use:

```cpp
template<typename F>
auto swap_two_args(F&& f) {
    return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&& l, auto&& r) {
        return f(std::forward<decltype(r)>(r), std::forward<decltype(l)>(l));
    };
}


// std::lower_bound(myVec.rbegin(), myVec.rend(), myVal,
    swap_two_args(valComp)
// );
```

Answer (score 1):

For the generic case, there isn't an adaptor in the standard library, but it is easy enough to write;

```cpp
template <typename Comp>
struct reversed_compare : Comp
{
    template <typename T1, typename T2>
    auto operator()(T1&& lhs, T2&& rhs) const
    {
        return Comp::operator()(std::forward<T2>(rhs), std::forward<T1>(lhs));
    }
};
```

For the specific case where you are reversing `<`, you can use `std::greater` (i.e. function object `>`)

```
std::lower_bound(myVec.rbegin(), myVec.rend(), myVal, std::greater{});
```

In C++14 you'd need `std::greater<>{}`, and in C++11 you'd need `std::greater<decltype(myVec)::value_type>{}` or similar.